# How to best implement this design issue?

Tags: java, design-patterns

We are refactoring a code that uses XML files to define various properties of an object. Lets call this object Report. There are different reports like annual, quarterly etc and others depending on clients. There are hundreds of such reports.

Currently we use JAXB to read these XML files and convert them into Report object and do the processing. There are lot of if and else involved in the code as depending on the properties set in the XML corresponding behavior needs to be implemented.

I was wondering whats the best possible way of implementing this in the new code. Note, I cannot modify the XML files.

Comment: Whats the target language?  And what exactly is in the `if`s and `else`s, is it *whether* some property in the report object is set or a `switch` over various values that a property can take?

Comment: This is for Java. The if s and else s are to define different behaviors. If a value is defined for a property in the XML do something. A property can be altogether missing in some xmls also.

Comment: What are the issues you're facing, why do you think you have to redesign an already existing solution? I do not want to challenge the question - just trying to understand it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to decouple.
ie split your report object into report description which is basically the parsed xml, and then have a set of classes that use it.

so you could have a method on reportdescription that returned a collection of report objects
e.g.reportheader, reportbody and reportfooter,

then reportbody.items would return groups.
reportgroups you return groupheader body footer etc

there'll still be as many ifs but it will be a lot cleaner.

PS if the current xml would benefit from a change in structure / format, an xsl transform shouldn't be a significant overhead, and could dramatically simply the code, may be.